# what does this error message for QUERY and IMPORT Range function on Google Sheets mean?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Audit Template!A1:AD994"), "SELECT a,b,c,g,p WHERE b = 'name’ AND p = 'yes'")
```

error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "yes "" at line 1, column 55. Was expecting one of:  "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "and" ... "or" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that if you use indirect range such as `IMPORTRANGE` then you need to use `Col` references:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Audit Template!A1:AD"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col7,Col16
  where Col2  = 'name' 
    and Col16 = 'yes'", 0)
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1gUxnjlhZlTgpw0gf-wuBgbf0zqmiKmoZKLCbfxQ6p5E", "Audit Template!A1:AD"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col7,Col16
  where Col1 contains 'name' 
    and Col16 = 'yes'", 1)
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gUxnjlhZlTgpw0gf-wuBgbf0zqmiKmoZKLCbfxQ6p5E/edit#gid=1754447548)

Comment: THANKS that works except there is no output. I am wondering if it doesn't take the output if the col 2 value is inside a dropdown menu (data validation) or if col 16 is a formula that outputs either yes or no

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19P9IhNgMgObCMnJOOVXt7BjtG818xvfC25HCwULrtU8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private, pls share it

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19P9IhNgMgObCMnJOOVXt7BjtG818xvfC25HCwULrtU8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry about that. hope you can get access now

Comment: Thank you so much!